# jQuery vulnerability (NVD CVE-2007-2379)

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

We're using jQuery and I've come across the following jQuery vulnerability in the National Vulnerability Database:

http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2007-2379

Has this been fixed in more recent versions of jQuery?  The original release date on the vulnerability is 4/30/2007.

I'm trying to ensure that the little jQuery we do use doesn't expose this vulnerability, does anyone have examples of it?

Comment: Starting from 1.4 version jQuery uses JSON parser build into browser (if it's available).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> If the specified URL is on a remote server, the request is treated as JSONP instead.

[Read about JSONP here](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/).

As long as you're using JSONP, this vulnerability doesn't exist.

Also, this 'vulnerability' is stupid. Anyone can exchange data using JSON, it's not just jQuery that uses it.

Comment: Using JSONP aggravates confidentiality of data.  If a JSONP service does not check the origin/referer headers or a CSRF token, a rogue site can define own callback that will receive the data when the victim surfs the site.  (JSONP worked around Same Origin policy.  CORS + XHR work the straight way).  As for the CVE, yes, modern browsers stopped calling setters and redefined constructors on executing an array as a script.  However Gareth Heyes demonstrated character encoding exploits when attackers control part of the data.  http://blog.portswigger.net/2016/11/json-hijacking-for-modern-web.html

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the problem *only* there when you use JSONP? It's all safe as long as all the sources are trusted.

As something inherent to JS, there's no way to fix it. Possibly, the XMLHttpRequest/CORS Cross-Origin Resource Sharing spec which is supported by many of the modern browsers (but requires the providing server to be configured to send out the CORS header) could be used instead of JSONP and using Douglas Crockford's JSON2 library (which also falls back on native browser JSON support if available).