# jQuery vulnerability (NVD CVE-2007-2379) - 'JSON data protection scheme' - solution in 2022?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

This is basically the same [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322261/jquery-vulnerability-nvd-cve-2007-2379) (I don't know how to avoid referencing it)
About [CVE-2007-2379](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2007-2379)

The reason I ask this again is since when I searched for a solution for this I [found a release note from 'January 2022' of Data Center Expert 7.9.0](https://dcimsupport.ecostruxureit.com/hc/en-us/articles/4406062022289-Data-Center-Expert-7-9-0-release-notes)

> Software vulnerabilities fixed in DCE 7.9.0
>
> - CVE-2007-2379 - JSON data protection scheme

I couldn't find any info on what is meant by "JSON data protection scheme" or any hint on how it was fixed

So my actual question is does anyone have any idea on what changed since 2010 that you can fix this issue and how to?

P.S: We are using jQuery 3.6 and scanning using Checkmarx's CxSCA this still appears as a security risk

Answer (score 1):

CORS became well supported so JS can fetch data cross-origin without using JSONP.

Comment: Thanks I will read on it, but just from the little I know. We basically limit the data each resource can get from us?

Comment: No. CORS lets you explicitly grant permission for certain origins to read data from a URL. (As opposed to JSONP where you embed the data in a JS program and ask anyone wanting the data to execute your program in their page)